# Hibernate: group by

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am trying to print some list of cities grouped by country with java + spring + hibernate + jasper reports but but have some issues with populating grouped list of cities...

I have the following query:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT city FROM DictionaryCity city JOIN city.country as country GROUP BY country ORDER BY country.name ASC");
```

that is always returns a list of cities but with 1x1 connection but `DictionaryCity` class defined the following way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dictionarycities")
public class DictionaryCity implements IDictionary {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3638441397996216204L;

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id = null;

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    /**
     * 
     */
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = DictionaryCountry.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CountryId")
    private DictionaryCountry country; /** other... **/ }
```

What is wrong? Thank you

Comment: What is the generated SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

group by doesn't have anything to do with returning similar rows grouped together. It's used when the select clause uses aggregate functions such as sum, min, max, count, etc.

For example, the query

```
select country.id, sum(city.id) from Country country left join country.cities city
```

returns each country along with the number of cities contained in this country.

If you just want to have groups of cities by country, `order by` is all you need:

```
select city FROM DictionaryCity city JOIN city.country as country order by country.name ASC
```

will return all the cities, and you'll find the cities of Azerbaidjan first, then those of Belgium, then those of Canada, etc.